# Does write command in init.rc create new folders?

Tags: android, kernel

I have few message on device boot about missing files or directories:

```
[    3.052514] init: write_file: Unable to open '/proc/cpu/alignment': No such file or directory
[    4.931333] init: write_file: Unable to open '/proc/sys/vm/min_free_order_shift': No such file or directory
```

I've founded out that init process tries to write values to these files via command

```
write /proc/cpu/alignment 4
```

[Documentation](https://chromium.googlesource.com/aosp/platform/system/core/+/master/init/readme.txt) says that `write` can create new file if it doesn't exist. But in result I can't find this file. Seams it wasn't created. Even more, there is no folder which should contain this file.

So can `write` command create a folder if it doesn't exist?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Filesystem under '/proc' is special in sence that all of its files are "created" by the *kernel*, and **user cannot create files there**.

This is *pseudo*-filesystem: its files are not stored on hard disk, but exist only in RAM and *reflect system properties*. Writing into this files changes properties in a special way. You cannot create new properties there.